# Can a definition be an assumption (antecedent of a conditional)?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Mean_Value_Theorem

Please refer to the proof 1 in the link given above, specifically the line:

> F(x) = f(x) + hx.

The thing I cannot wrap my head around is, why is the above-mentioned line not an assumption (of a conditional)? Surely, we are **assuming** that F(x) is equal to f(x) + hx ? And that, on the truth of this premiss do the truth of the statements that follow, depend?

I can understand that the statement in question is a definition. But I'm just unable to convince myself that F(x) = f(x) + hx is **not** an assumption. Can definitions (both, as in the proof, and generally) be assumptions? What would be the specific problem if we take the line to be an assumption? And, **if** the statement really acts as an assumption, till where is its scope, i.e., where exactly is it discharged?

To be clear, I do not mean this question in the context of this particular proof of the Mean Value Theorem. A similar question could as well arise in other proofs of this kind.

Thanks for your consideration. I'm a self-learner, so please be understanding.

Comment: The function $F(x)$ has been created using the "already" defined function $f(x)$ and the well-known linear function $hx$. Whatever attributes we now claim for the created object $F$ will follow from theorems and existing properties of $f$ and $hx$ (no assumptions here).

Comment: Notice that $F$ doesn't appear anywhere in the statement of the theorem, only in the proof? And that the statement of the theorem doesn't claim anything about $F$? You could write this up so that $F$ appears in the statement, along with an assumption about it, but you would gain nothing, and would actually make the statement confusing. If you're used to any programming language like C or Python, $F$'s scope is entirely within a function - there is no point to pass it in as an argument.

Comment: Am I right in understanding that the statement in question **is** an assumption, but since the F in it does not appear in the statement of the theorem, we do not need to discharge the assumption?

Comment: No it is not an assumption. It is the *definition* of $F$. They are defining a new function $F$ by the formula $F(x) = f(x) + hx$.

Comment: @SayanSarkar - To be honest I don't recognize the term "discharge the assumption". And I'm not sure if I learned the same concept under a different name, or if I'm just not familiar with the concept. So if your last comment was directed at me, I'm afraid i can't answer.